# Stop subdomain redirects to main domain in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, subdomain

I have a website that is build in WordPress.

I want to build the sub-domains for the site according to the states same as **"olx.in"** do for different cities.

Everything is setup from the code, server and hosting side, but the problem I am facing is that when I type any sub-domain in the URL like **"rj.mysite.com"** then I there is somewhere somthing written in the wordpress php file, that is redirecting me to the main domain because I made many changes in the .htaccess file but nothing worked out.

I have tried so much but couldn't found the script that is redirecting the sub-domains to the main domain.

Can anybody please tell me that what should be there in the php code of WordPress that is redirecting my sub-domains to the main site?

Comment: check .htacces file setup for redirection

Comment: Can you please tell which OS you are using

Comment: mod-rewrite should be enabled first

Comment: I think this might be a dns domain issue rather than Wordpress/.htaccess, how have you set up DNS for the sub-domain rj.mysite.com

Comment: @SergeiZahharenko...I have checked the .htaccess file setup but nothing works from the there

Comment: @Ashish.. My site is live and I have purchased hosting and server

Comment: @XTian.. I have checked this with a subdomain wildcard entry on the server and also with different subdomains for each state but nothing work out

Answer (score 2):

just found the answer today, hope you've solved it, assuming you have,
what i did for mine was create another wp-config.php file, named it wp-config-sub.php, then in your sub domain, require the wp-config-sub.php file, instead of the wp-config.php file,

```
    require_once '../wp-config-sub.php';
```

then go back to your wp-config-sub.php file and comment out these lines

```
/* Multisite */
//define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
//define('MULTISITE', true);
//define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
//define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'yoursiteprimaryurl.com');
//define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
//define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
//define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

hope this will solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

if everything correct in the NS records and the domain redirects
I think you need to login to wordpress and change in the general settings

WordPress Address (URL)
and
Site Address (URL)

to your sub domain or to check your .htaccess file

Comment: @Momtaz... can you elaborate this?

Comment: you need to check what urls u set in when you install the wordpress or in the .htaccess file, if your wordpress is on your own server then try to access the .htaccess and share with us.

Comment: I checked my general settings and everything looks fine.

WordPress Address (URL) : mysite.com

Site Address (URL) : mysite.com

Comment: what about the .htaccess file?

Comment: I have tried many changes in the .htaccess file but nothing works for me.

There must be some problem with WordPress php code becasue if I put die() at the end of wp-config.php file then it will not redirect the subdomain.